# Merging PDFs with Sejda fails with stream output

Tags: java, pdf, sejda

Using Sejda 1.0.0.RELEASE, I basically followed the [tutorial for splitting a PDF](http://www.sejda.org/development/quick-start/) but tried merging instead (`org.sejda.impl.itext5.MergeTask`, `MergeParameters`, ...). All works great with the `FileTaskOutput`:

```
parameters.setOutput(new FileTaskOutput(new File("/some/path/merged.pdf")));
```

However I am unable to change this to `StreamTaskOutput` correctly:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/some/path/merged.pdf");
parameters.setOutput(new StreamTaskOutput(os));
parameters.setOutputName("merged.pdf");
```

No error is reported, but the resulting file cannot be read by Preview.app and is approximately 31 kB smaller (out of the ~1.2 MB total result) than the file saved above.

My first idea was: stream is not being closed properly! So I added `os.close();` to the end of `CompletionListener`, still the same problem.

Remarks:

- The reason I need to use `StreamTaskOutput` is that this merge logic will live in a web app, and the merged PDF will be sent directly over HTTP. I could store the temporary file and serve that one, but that is a hack.
- Due to licencing issues, I cannot use the iText 5 version of the task.

---

### Edit

Turns out, the reason is that `StreamTaskOutput` zips the result into a ZIP file! `OutputWriterHelper.copyToStream()` is the culprit. If I rename `merged.pdf` to `merged.zip`, it's a valid ZIP file containing a perfectly valid `merged.pdf` file!

Could anyone (dear authors of the library) comment on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that when a task consumes a `MultipleOutputTaskParameters` producing multiple output documents, the `StreamTaskOutput` has to group them to be able to write all of them to a stream output. Unfortunately Sejda currently applies the same logic to `SingleOutputTaskParameters`, hence your issue. We can fix this in Sejda 2.0 because it makes more sense to directly stream the out document in case of `SingleOutputTaskParameters`. For Sejda 1.x I'm not sure how to address this remaining compatible with the existing behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Let's suppose the only thing I use Sejda for is this PDF merging. How could I fix this behavior in a Sejda fork? Could I just assert that `files` parameter in `copyToStream()` contains one file only and just stream it to the `out` parameter?

Comment: I don't the code at hand but I'd check the number of files in the copyToStream, if one stream it, if more fallback to the old behaviour.